# How to skip first line of input file in C?

Tags: c, file, input, file-io, output

I am new at C programming. I have an input file and I want to skip first line of the input file and try to compose output file.My file contains some graph information. I want to get u,v,w values from input file instead of user enters.But I am getting no value for u,v,w.

```
printf("Enter (u v w):\n");
    for(i = 0; i < edges; ++i){
        scanf("%d%d%d", &u, &v, &w);
     }
```

I tried like this :

```
fgets(buffer, 1024, inputFile);       
        while( ( ch = fgetc(inputFile) ) != EOF )   
        {
         sscanf(buffer, "%d%d%d", &u, &v, &w);
          }
```

Comment: What does the data look like?

Comment: it contains just numbers like: 1 2 3

Comment: Your algorithm says: read a line. Then, while throwing away characters one at a time from the file, repeatedly scan the first (and only) line read for three `int` values? Not sure that was your intent, but I'm guessing not.

Comment: No,  to skip only first line is enough for me. Other lines contain graph information.

Comment: Something tells me `while( ( ch = fgetc(inputFile) ) != EOF )` was supposed to be something like: `while( fgets(buffer, 1024, inputFile) )`, or something similar. That assuming your intent on scanning `buffer` repeatedly for 3 `int` values was to perform per-line processing and reading the first three (and only the first three) `int` values, ignoring the rest of each line of anything extraneous.

Comment: duplicate. There is on liner solution described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16108311

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this:

```
fscanf(inputFile, "%*[^\n]"); // Read and discard a line
while(fscanf(inputFile, "%d%d%d", &u, &v, &w) == 3 )   
{
    ...
}
```

---

Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int u, v, w;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    if (!fp)
    {
        perror("fopen()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fscanf(fp, "%*[^\n]");  // Read and discard a line
    while (fscanf(fp, "%d%d%d", &u, &v, &w) == 3)
    {
        printf("%d %d %d\n", u, v, w);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

data.txt

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

output:

```
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Comment: I tried but nothing made difference.

Comment: @zeynep What do you mean by "made difference"? It failed?

Comment: Nothing changed. I get same result.

Comment: @zeynep I'm going to check my code

Comment: @zeynep It seems to work well. Can you run my example code?

Comment: Thanks @sun qingyao it prints u,v and w values, but actually I want to compose graph. I could not print graph information to my output file. fscanf(inputFile, "%d%d%d", &u, &v, &w); Graph[u][v] = Graph[v][u] = w;for(i = 0; i < nodes; ++i){
        for(j = 0; j < nodes; ++j)
        fprintf(outputFile, "%d%s",Graph[i][j]," ");} My output file is empty.

Comment: @zeynep Can you show us the full code? Please append it to your question.