# Skip Line with fscanf

Tags: c

I am getting the following compiler warning when I use the following to skip a line when reading a file with fscanf with C:

```
warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
fscanf(myFile, "%*[^\n]\n", NULL);
```

The program works perfectly fine.  However, I wonder if there is an approach to skip a line in a file that is as minimalistic as the above and does not give compiler warnings (or a simple edit to the above would be ideal)?  This approach to skipping a line was taken from [How to skip the first line when fscanning a .txt file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799612/how-to-skip-the-first-line-when-fscanning-a-txt-file) where there is no mention of any such warning.  Other methods of skipping a line are presented in this previous question; however, none are as minimalistic as the above.

Comment: `fscanf(myFile, "%*[^\n]\n", NULL);` --> `fscanf(myFile, "%*[^\n]\n");`  but other code would be better.

Comment: Simple.  To the point.  No more compiler warning.  Cheers, @chux.

Comment: You should be aware that although the `fscanf()` call will only return 0 (or EOF if there is no more input when it starts scanning), it will only read a newline if there is at least one non-newline character before the next newline. If you want line based input, don't use the `scanf()` family of functions; use [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) (or, on POSIX machines, use
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)). You can then use `sscanf()` to parse the line if appropriate.

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks, Jonathan! I will look into fgets() as both you and chux suggest that this implementation of fscanf may not be the best choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the NULL. The warning is because the compiler understood from the `*` that you dont want to store the result anywhere (but just advance the file with the specified pattern). But then it gets somehow "surprised" that you specify a location (be it NULL).

Comment: Thanks so much @A.S.H, makes perfect sense.  No more warning.  Happy New Year!